# Remote desktop from Windows Mobile to Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, windows-phone

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, I'm wondering is there a any possibility, to share remote desktop from Windows Mobile Pocket PC device.

Like `ActiveSync Remote Display`, from `MS Windows Mobile Developer Power Toys`.
First I would like to try establish connection using ActiveSync, to check if this working with Wine.
I think it's a first thing worth to try, but maybe some known alternatives?

I was looking for `SynCE`, but it's damnably hard to find those packets good to my system, maybe some of you have a clear directions what to do, to bring `SynCE` to my system.
But like I've said, I'm also open on alternatives :)

Any tips what should I try, any ideas or alternative routes, to solve this?

Comment: I too would love to be able to talk to my old Pocket PC (running Windows Mobile 4.2) with my Ubuntu 14.04 computer.  Any help appreciated.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, on the first try I didn't found anything that works with Windows CE 5.2, just old bunch of software that didn't work for me.

But yesterday, I give it a try again and I found EfonVNC Server, it works great with any machine equipped with VNC Client that wants to connect it, Android, Linux, Windows. But EfonVNC require version of Windows CE 5.0 or above it.

Here is the [EfonVNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/efonvnc/files/efonvnc/efonvnc_v4.3/) VNC Server download

[image: Remina VNC Client]

For older versions of Windows CE unfortunately I cannot help cause I'm not able to test it. But if you find something by yourself, you may want to share with here to help someone else in future.

Hope my answer will be helpful for someone. Regards.